# How to export a column data in excel to a text file using a vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I want to export the data contained in column H in an excel file using a vba code. I managed to get the code, but i want to modify it to allow me to choose the name and the directory to save it before creating it.Thanks in advance
The code is

```
Sub Export()

Dim i As Long, derLig As Long, tabl

derLig = Range("H" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
tabl = Range("H1:H" & derLig)
Open "D:\CCP.txt" For Output As #1
For i = 1 To UBound(tabl, 1)
If tabl(i, 1) <> "" Then
Print #1, tabl(i, 1)
End If
Next
Close #1
MsgBox ("Le Fichier CCP A Eté Créé Dans Le Disque D")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` to prompt for a location and name for the file.

Comment: Can you do it for me Tim Williams.

Comment: Have you tried Tim's suggestion? What's your code?

Comment: I didn't manage to do it

Comment: A good way to get help here is *show what you tried* - post the code you wrote to try to use `GetSaveAsFileName` and tell us what happened when you tried to run it.  You got an error? - if Yes, what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Export()

    Dim i As Long, n As Long, derLig As Long, tabl
    Dim filename As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("H:H")) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "pas de données à sauvegarder", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        derLig = .Range("H" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        tabl = .Range("H1:H" & derLig)
    End With
    
    filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
    If Len(filename) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "nom de fichier non valide", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Open filename For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To UBound(tabl, 1)
        If tabl(i, 1) <> "" Then
            Print #1, tabl(i, 1)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next
    Close #1
    MsgBox n & " lignes écrites dans " & filename, vbInformation
  
End Sub
```